# Are there techniques for interpreting practical viability of some method?

Tags: publications

Are there techniques for interpreting practical viability of some method?

That is, if one comes across some mentioned technique, then is there some way to gauge, how much prevalence it has for practical usage? Some theories may stay at a theoretical level for some time, and they're perhaps not a good use of time for someone, who is interested in usable techiques.

Consider, e.g.:

[https://www.amazon.com/Boltzmann-Application-Engineering-Advances-Computational/dp/9814508292](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9814508292)

> With these coverage LBM, **the book is intended to promote its applications**, instead of the traditional computational fluid dynamic method.

Are there e.g. particular keywords to search for in journal archives or something?

Comment: Please consider extending your question as to what class of problems you are trying to solve.

Comment: @MPIchael Nothing in particular, I'm just looking for search words or something that I could use for finding such information in a general case. Or, possibly, if there are journals that focus particularly on "well-tested methods".

Answer (score 2):

There are several benchmark papers that focus on one physical/mathematical problem and then compare the numerical methods along several metrics. Typically the authors of these papers have no conflicting interests when it comes to one particular numerical method. You can use the search term "Benchmark of numerical methods for <Your Problem>".

[anisotropic diffusion](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00429843/document)

[boiling flow](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/260110105_Benchmarks_and_numerical_methods_for_the_simulation_of_boiling_flows)

[incompressible flow](https://www.wias-berlin.de/people/john/ELECTRONIC_PAPERS/JM01.IJNMF.pdf)